# How to force file-queue-store to keep messages on disk

Tags: mule, persistent

For asynchronous processing large amount of files it could be nice to store messages in a persistent storage to releave JVM heap and avoid data loss in case of system failure.
I configured file-queue-store, but unfortunatelly, I can not see msg files in the .mule/queuestore/myqueuename folder.
I feed the flow with files from smb:endpoint and send them to a cxf endpoint.
When I stop Mule ESB (version 3.2.0) properly during file processing, it writes a lot of .msg files to the queuestore. After restart it processes them one-by-one.
But, when I kill the JVM (to test a system failure, or OutOfMemoryError, etc.), there is no fies in the queuestore, so all of the is lost.
My question: Is it possible to force queuestore to store the messages on disk and delete them only when they fully processed?
Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your config?

Comment: Can you give it a try on Mule 3.4.0? It's maybe a bug that has long been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Mule 3.2.0 was affected by this [issue](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6102)

You should consider upgrading.